# Access Vuex State from VueRouter

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to wrap my head around Navigation Guards for vue.js. I tried to follow the example but I think I am falling short in connecting my State (store.js) to my Router (routes.js). In my Login.vue component I try and push to a new route after the loadUser has dispatched to the State and subsequently the isLoggedIn is updated to true. In the vue components I use mapState do I need to do the same thing here in routes.js. Or maybe there is a better way to do this. To give a full picture I am using a vue frontend and laravel backend with Sanctum.

Extract from routes.js

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Login,
        name: 'login'
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        component: Dashboard,
        name: 'dashboard',
        meta: { requiresAuth: true }
    },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes // short for `routes: routes`
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
        if (store.state.isLoggedIn) {
            next();
        } else {
            next({
                name: 'home'
            });
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

export default router;
```

Extract from store.js

```
export default {
    state : {
        isLoggedIn: false,
    }
}
```

Extract from Login.vue

```
methods : {
        async login() {
            this.loading = true;
            this.errors = null;

            try {
                await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
                await axios.post('/login', this.user);

                logIn();
                this.$store.dispatch('loadUser');
                this.$router.push({ name: 'logbook'});

            } catch (error) {
                this.errors = error.response && error.response.data.errors;
            }

            this.loading = false;
        }
    },
```

Comment: Maybe I should move the redirect from the vue component to router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access/change the Vuex in VueRouter, you must to use the command `router.app.store.state...`.

For example:

```js
const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Login, name: 'login' },
  { path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard, name: 'dashboard', meta: { requiresAuth: true } },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (router.app.$store) {
    // Example to access the state
    console.log(router.app.$store.state.isLoggedIn);

    // Example to exec the mutation
    router.app.$store.commit('myMutation', 'myArgs');

    // Example to exec the action (ATTENTION IS ASYNC)
    router.app.$store.dispatch('myAction', 'myArgs');
  }

  if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
    // ...
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

Attention: 
You must load the Vuex first than VueRouter. Because, when the VueRouter load the Vuex need to be ready. You can change this in `main.js`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store' // FIRST IMPORT
import router from './router' // SECOND IMPORT

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Other thing, I prefer to control of login in cookies, because the user can open many tabs. It's my opinion, you can to do what you prefer.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)